# Instrument volatility scaling as a function of sample rate

Tags: volatility

## Question:

I did some experimentation today to see if volatility changes as a function of the sample frequency.

Prior to starting this experiment, I believed that volatility was a function of sample frequency and that the scaling should be like $\sqrt T$. It might be that I have totally misunderstood something.

What I found by performing my experiment is that volatility is approximatly constant.

I will now explain what I did:

- I obtained data for the closing price of `TLT` which is an instrument which gives exposure to US Treasury Bonds
- I have two years of data, from 2022 and 2023
- The data native sample rate is 1 minute bins, although some bins for very quiet trading days are missing (24th November after 13:00 being an obvious example)
- I resampled this data at intervals of 1 minute, 5 minute, 15 minute, 60 minute and 1440 minute (24 hours)
- I discarded any data which was not within NASDAQ trading hours (09:30 - 16:00) and I discarded any data which was not within NASDAQ trading days, which included both weekends and holidays as determined by `pandas_market_calendars`
- I calculated the **change in closing price** from the closing price data
- I calculated the standard deviation of changes in closing price
- I calculated the annualized standard deviation of changes in closing price by scaling by $\sqrt N$ where N is the number of periods

For example:

```
annualized_std_24_hour = math.sqrt(256) * std_24_hour
```

because there are (approximately) 256 blocks of 24 hours in a year. (Trading days.)

For the final resampling, data was resampled each day at `15:00 America/New_York`, so that a closing price is taken from within trading hours.

The following dataframe contains my results.

```
   time_period   count       std  annualized_std
0            1  283865  0.054267       32.948647
1            5   57353  0.119761       32.518706
2           15   19601  0.203873       31.960574
3           60    5081  0.403402       31.620142
4         1440     725  1.036977       16.591634
```

There is one obvious outlier here. The resampled at daily frequency data is notably different to the others.

Why is this the case? Am I calculating the volatility (std) here correctly?

## Possible Hypothesis 1:

I had one hypothesis:

- Perhaps because more volume of this instrument is traded between the hours of `09:30` and `16:00` (6.5 hours), and because almost no trades are made during the night (far outside of trading hours) the scaling factor to convert between days and hours is wrong.
- The scaling factor I was using was 24 hours / day. Perhaps it should be 6.5 hours / day.

The dataframe below shows the results for 6.5 hours / day.

```
   time_period   count       std  annualized_std
0            1  283865  0.054267       17.147019
1            5   57353  0.119761       16.923271
2           15   19601  0.203873       16.632810
3           60    5081  0.403402       16.455644
4         1440     725  1.036977       16.591634
```

All of the values for periods shorter than 1 day are over-estimated compared to the value for 1 day.

*I understand that this could just be by chance and might not be statistically significant. Looking at the values I don't think it is just random noise.*

## Possible Hypothesis 2:

It then occurred to me that NASDAQ has 252 trading days in a year. The difference might become significant at this level of precision.

The same table of values calculated for 252 trading days.

```
   time_period   count       std  annualized_std
0            1  283865  0.054267       17.012531
1            5   57353  0.119761       16.790538
2           15   19601  0.203873       16.502355
3           60    5081  0.403402       16.326578
4         1440     725  1.036977       16.461502
```

I would suggest it is now even harder to tell if there is any significance here.

Comment: Consider using automatic spell check next time.

Comment: @RichardHardy how do I do that?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way would be to turn it on in your browser settings/options.

Comment: @RichardHardy I don't know why it's not working, I'm not going to waste my time investigating either